# Is there any way to float 4 elements horizontally on a single web page

Tags: html

I am trying to automate a form that has four different columns with html/css and perl. Is there any way I can split the page into 4 different horizontal sections with float or another html format?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Sure, create four floated divs. What problem are you having?

Comment: if I understand your question correctly, you want 4 block to behave like colums? Do you mean vertical or horizontal? float: left; and width: 25%; on your blocks should do the trick.

Comment: 4 columns going up and down on a page. Would I be able to create floated div's which would allow me to split the page (There's only left, right, and none right) Sorry I'm really new to html

Comment: ah you mean vertically, then the jsFiddle link below is correct. Consider using percentage for the width property for your containers. It makes it more fluid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use float and a fixed width on the divs:

```
<!-- Your html markup. The 4 columns as div elements-->
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

// the css code for aligning the columns
div{
     border:1px solid red;
     margin:5px;
     width:100px;
     height:400px;
     float:left; 
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fN8BJ/)

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to float these columns, you'll need to specify them as `display:block;` with a `width` for each of them so that they know where their edges are. If you have a fixed width site, just set their widths to be 25% of the site's, and then `float` them left. If you don't know what the width of the site will be, but you still want the columns to fill the page, it gets trickier in older browsers. Best go with the first option.